# Why does while(arr.length) behave this way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the code

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

while (arr.length) {
  console.log(arr[arr.length - 1]);
  arr.pop();
}
```

the output for this code is

```
3
2
1
1
```

but I expected

```
3
2
1
```

when I switch the code to

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

while (arr.length) {
  console.log(arr[arr.length - 1]);
  arr.pop();
}
console.log();
```

I get

```
3
2
1
```

Why does it behave this way? Why am I getting a duplicate in the first code example? How can I prevent this?
Thanks

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+console+extra+output+after+loop+ends) of [Javascript while loop return value](/q/35454291/4642212). This is [what your console shows you](//i.stack.imgur.com/dbOG9.png). `← 1` is _not_ a log output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run the script anywhere else other than in the browser console and it'll behave normally.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3];

while (arr.length) {
  console.log(arr[arr.length - 1]);
  arr.pop();
}
```

For example, on a webpage, the code would work just fine.

In the console, the final expression in the block is the completion value of the block. Here, that's the final value popped, which is 1. So 1 is the completion value of the `while` loop, which browsers will then log for you when the while loop is the final block in the code.

You could also *just ignore* the completion value of the code, and only look at what gets logged by the code itself, eg

[image]

which is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Comment: Doh, don't tell anyone I asked this question.... Thanks for your answer. I will accept in 10 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr = [1,2,3];
i = arr.length - 1;
while (i > -1) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
  i--;
}
```